# Developing week of month method

Tags: java, methods

Basically in the following method I'm trying to say: If z2 does not equal 0, z2 - 1. else add 6 to z2. I know it's probably stupid but I'm quite new to programming. The code as follows:

```
int z2 = someValue;

    if(z2 != 0){
        z2--;
        }
    else{
         z2 + 6;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: `z2 + 6` -> `z2 = z2 + 6;`? You need to assign the result of the calculation

Comment: and what exactly is your question?

Comment: Should be `z2 += 6` (or even `z2 = 6` since it'll always be `0` anyway). For the rest I don't see any problem.

Comment: If it's not for exercise: `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)`  and as of Java 8 `LocalDate.now().get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *assign* `z2` to a value in the `else` condition:

```
if (z2 != 0) {
    z2--;         // same as z2 = z2 - 1
}
else {
    z2 += 6;      // same as z2 = z2 + 6
}
```

But we could do this with a single line of code, using a ternary expression:

```
z2 = z2 != 0 ? z2 - 1 : z2 + 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

The math operation for that is **modulo**, in java the operator `%`, remainder of division.

```
|   x | x % 3 |
|-----|-------|
|   6 |   0   |
|   5 |   2   |
|   4 |   1   |
|   3 |   0   |
|   2 |   2   |
|   1 |   1   |
|   0 |   0   |
|  -1 |  -1   |
|  -2 |  -2   |
|  -3 |   0   |
|  -4 |  -1   |
```

Using integer division `/` (5/3 == 1):

> y % x == y - x * (y / x)

Notice the sign when one of the sides is negative.

In your case a decrement becomes:

```
z2 = (z2 - 1 + 7) % 7;
```

or short

```
z2 = (z2 + 6) % 7;
```

Care has been taken that the left hand side of `%` remains positive. The result then is in `0 .. 6`.

> For those interested in latin **modulus** is actually called the operation (a noun), but in an expression gets the adverbal ending `o` (ablativus): **"34 modulo 7 is 6"**. But **modulo** will do fine used as noun.